# Nexus 10 gets stuck "Google" boot screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-10

I just tried to install Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 10 according to your manual.

The terminal said at the end that I have to wait for a reboot of my Nexus 10 and afterwards it will run on Ubuntu. Unfortunately I get stuck on the black screen after the screen with the white Google text shortly after booting.

How can I get the system running and if there are any problems, how can I reflash Android?

I tried it with an Android tool but it cannot find my device it says something with *"no adb"*.

Comment: I answered this recently for **Nexus 7**. Is this resolved?

Comment: I had the same problem (still do) and from what I understand, ubuntu modifies the recovery partition so the only way to get back to android is by re-installing it through adb (fastboot).
check out http://www.androidbeat.com/2013/11/flash-factory-image-nexus-device/ I hope this helps
Cheers oops, I just saw you dont have adb. you must have Android sdk installed in order for this to work.
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

How to fix the boot loop on the Nexus 10:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1Se7Hr9Cww